# Select entity with related many-to-many keys only in TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

With a many-to-many relation, is it possible to *automatically* select just the related foreign keys, without selecting the whole related objects? Without using additional logic like query builders to explicitly join the relation table.

Suppose I have `Bank` and `Country` entities, with a many-to-many relation (some banks operate in more than one country). Here's what I'd want to achieve:

```js
@Entity()
export class Country {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;
  // ... other columns
}

@Entity
export class Bank {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  // ... other columns

  @ManyToMany(_type => Country)
  @JoinTable()
  countries?: Country[];

  // TODO: how to achieve this without tricks?
  countryIds?: number[];
}
```

With a one-to-many relation, it was possible to use `@JoinColumn(name: 'countryId')` on the relation, and then `@Column() countryId: number`.

Is something similar possible for many-to-many relations, to select just the foreign keys into the entity, but without selecting the whole related countries, and without using a query builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using [@RelationId](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#relationid), the country ids are then eager-loaded, so you don't need any additional queries:

```
@Entity()
 export class Bank { 
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() 
    id!: number; 
    @ManyToMany(_type => Country) 
    @JoinTable() 
    countries?: Country[];

    @RelationId('countries')
    countryIds?: number[];
```